# Swift 3 Trivia app Duplicate answers

Tags: ios, swift3

[image: the Problem]

This is my code, The correct answer randomizes its position in the number of buttons. however, the current code seems to duplicate the 4th answer

It does this for every question and their respective set of answers.

The buttons tags are setup simply, the first one is tagged "1" and the 2nd button is tagged "2" and so on.

If any more info is needed feel free to ask.

I've left the problem code so that others who have similar issues will have a base to see what I did wrong.

Problem Code:

```
//
//  AnimalViewController.swift
//  It's Trival
//
//  Created by Chris Levely on 12/18/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 ZenithNomad. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class AnimalViewController: UIViewController {

    let questions = ["What is the fastest fish in the sea?", "Which animal has the most legs?"]
    let answers = [["Sailfish", "Tuna", "Swordfish", "Marlin"], ["Millipede", "Spider", "Ant", "Octopus"]]

    var currentQuestion = 0
    var rightAnswerPlacement : UInt32 = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var Question: UILabel!

    @IBAction func AnswerQuestion(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerPlacement))
        {
            print("Right")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Wrong")
        }

        if (currentQuestion != questions.count)
        {
            newQuestion()
        }
    }

    func newQuestion()
    {
        Question.text = questions[currentQuestion]

        rightAnswerPlacement = arc4random_uniform(4)+1

        var button : UIButton = UIButton()

        var x = 1

        for i in 1...4
        {
            button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton

            if (i == Int(rightAnswerPlacement))
            {
                button.setTitle(answers[currentQuestion][0], for: .normal)
            }
            else
            {
                button.setTitle(answers[currentQuestion][x], for: .normal)
                x = 3
            }


        }
        currentQuestion += 1
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        newQuestion()
    }

}
```

New Fixed Code:

```
    //
//  AnimalViewController.swift
//  It's Trival
//
//  Created by Chris Levely on 12/18/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 ZenithNomad. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class AnimalViewController: UIViewController {

    let questions = ["What is the fastest fish in the sea?", "Which animal has the most legs?"]
    let answers = [["Sailfish", "Tuna", "Swordfish", "Marlin"], ["Millipede", "Spider", "Ant", "Octopus"]]

    var currentQuestion = 0
    var rightAnswerPlacement : UInt32 = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var Question: UILabel!

    @IBAction func AnswerQuestion(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerPlacement))
        {
            print("Right")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Wrong")
        }

        if (currentQuestion != questions.count)
        {
            newQuestion()
        }
    }

    func newQuestion()
    {
        Question.text = questions[currentQuestion]

        rightAnswerPlacement = arc4random_uniform(4)+1

        var button : UIButton = UIButton()

        var x = 1

        for i in 1...4
        {
            button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton

            if (i == Int(rightAnswerPlacement))
            {
                button.setTitle(answers[currentQuestion][0], for: .normal)
            }
            else
            {
                button.setTitle(answers[currentQuestion][x], for: .normal)
                x += 1
            }


        }
        currentQuestion += 1
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        newQuestion()
    }

}
```

Comment: why `answers[currentQuestion][x]`? with an hardcoded `x` being 1 the first time, then 3 all the other times?

Comment: x=1 is because I do not want to access 0 in the array because that is the correct answer. that only needs to be accessed once. so I start the value at 1. I should not have hardcoded x =3 towards the end, however. just need to increment it for each button so it moves forward in the string array.

Comment: "_I should not have hardcoded x =3_", oh well, so you got your answer to your own question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was a little more simple than randomizing the x value. In my sample code above I have it written as x =1 to start and then in the newQuestion function as x = 3,

The solution that I have gone with, I now have it as x+=1 so it now goes through the array for each loop instead of sticking with the 4th answer in the array. may not be the most elegant of solutions but it is all that is required for this simple app

Answer (score 2):

It is because you hardcode x = 3, you should randomize x as well.

Here is my approach, I test it using UILabel, but it is the same concept

```
func newQuestion()
{
    questionLabel.text = questions[currentQuestion]
    var label : UILabel = UILabel()
    var xArray = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    var x = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xArray.count)))

    for i in 1...4
    {

        label = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UILabel
        label.text = answers[currentQuestion][xArray[x]]

        if answers[currentQuestion][xArray[x]] == answers[currentQuestion][0]
        {
            print(answers[currentQuestion][xArray[x]])
            //this is the answer, do something when user click this button
        }

        //remove the index x because you don't want to get a same number next time
        xArray.remove(at: x)
        x = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xArray.count)))

    }
    currentQuestion += 1
}
```

[image]

Comment: when I try to do as you said and randomize the x value. in the same way, you have here. I get even more duplicates. except now, it duplicates a random answer and sometimes more than once

Comment: can you update your code on the new method that you implemented?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the fix to my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that before you set the title of the correct answer to a random button you first set the title of all the buttons in the same order of the array of possible answers, no problem there, now you set the string of the right answer to a random button, if this random position is not the same as the position of the right answer in the array (0), you end up with a duplicate string, that is what is actually happening.

What you need to do is to switch the answer at position 0 (right answer) with another answer at a random position in the array or even better shuffle the array of answers, how? I think there isn't a built-in function, but you could create a new empty array and remove a random answer from the original array and add it to the new one until all the answers switch from the original array to the new one in a random order.

Hope it helps.